# Как узнать страницу открытого pdf файла

Tags: javascript, html, html5, pdf

Добрый день! Я хочу отобразить .pdf файл в HTML, использовал такую конструкцию:

```
<object data="D:\Java.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" id="pdf">
  <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="D:\Java.pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>
</object>
```

Нигде не нашел информацию, есть ли возможность используя JavaScript узнать на какой странице в данный момент открыт документ?
Буду благодарен любому ответу!

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "на какой странице"? Вы хотите узнать адрес страницы? вкладку в браузере?

Comment: @Romanzhivo Нет, я хочу узнать, на какой странице в открытом pdf документе я нахожусь. Например, я хочу сохранять последнюю открытую страницу пользователя в pdf документе, что бы в следующий раз, pdf документ открывался на этой странице. Возможно ли такое сделать ?

Comment: думаю, можно, но реализация показа pdf в каждом браузере своя. В Хроме pdf встраивается через тег <embed>, а все элементы интерфейса для управления (показ номера страницы и пр.) реализованы через Shadow DOM. В ФФ pdf транслирован в разметку, и страницы отображаются как блоки div-ов. Полагаю, универсальную реализацию для всех браузеров написать вряд ли возможно, однако можно попробовать для каждого конкретного браузера. 

Но если показ pdf контролируется вами, то можно использовать обычные приёмы с якорями или отслеживанием значения прокрутки, например, window.scrollY

Comment: @Romanzhivo Я понял, спасибо за информацию. Буду думать. Может быть попробую на стороне сервера пропарсить, и на клиент-сайд закинуть фотки, или что то в этом роде)